# Is the tree still connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = \langle V,E\rangle$ be a tree. Prove that if $v \in V$ and $\deg(v) \ge 2$ if you remove $v$ the tree becomes unconnected.

It seems obvious but I can't state a formal prove.

Comment: what is the definition of tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **tree** is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one simple path. Let $u\in V$ be a vertex of $G$. By definition of tree, there is unique between $u$ and $v$. So, if you remove $v$ from $G$, then there does not exist path between $u$ and $v$. Thus, $v$ and $u$ are in different connected components.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Trees are characterized by the fact that there is a unique path between any two vertices.

Comment: Hmm... Ok so if I can prove that there is a unique path between every two vertices I will prove that when removing a vertice the path is gone and the tree is unconnected, right ? So how to prove the unique path theorem?

Comment: ok, i think i have the prove. Gonna post it soon

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: In a tree there is a unique path between any two vertices.

Let's assume that in the tree exists a pair which is connected by two paths.

$P1 = (u,u1,…,ui,r1,r2,…,rj−1,rj,ui+1,…,v)$
$P2=(u,u1,…,ui,s1,s2,…,sk−1,sk,ui+1,…,v)$

Now consider the path :

$P3 = (ui,r1,r2,…,rj−1,rj,ui+1,sk,sk−1…,s2,s1,ui)$

It's obvius that P3 is a circuit.
Lemma is true.

Let $v_i$ be a vertical